# Xfce4 Disable Wallpaper Blurring

Tags: xfce, desktop-background, antialiasing

I'm trying to set up some pixel art wallpapers in xfce(4.12), but they're getting blurred, is there any way to disable this? Scaling the images larger should not only be unnecessary, but doesn't work very well either.

Comment: Let me clarify. Is this only a problem with pixel art type of wallpapers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's my guess that this occurs when you resize/scale the image.  If you want to stop automatic resizing, right-click on your desktop, select **Desktop Settings** and change the resizing method to **Centered**.  This actually disables resizing and just centers the image.

If you do that though and your wallpaper is larger than the screen size, you will have to resize it using an app, like **gimp** for example.

Comment: I'd like it to resize the image without any interpolation, but if that's not possible (though it should be), I'll have to scale and crop images as you said

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I believe the most effective way to choose the style is to centre the background.

[image]